# how to make growing div not overflowing its parent that contains also fixed div above

Tags: html, css, layout

In the code below the main div has `max-height` set to `100%` (of its parent that has `300px` height). This main div contains two child: one with fixed height and the second with `flex-grow: 1` and its child with lots of content has set `overflow-x: scroll`.

The problem is that the second child with its big sub-child does not want to behave and scroll nicely but are rude and overflow their parent (the main div).
How to solve it?

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body style="height: 300px; max-height: 300px; margin: 0px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div style="height: 100%; max-height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin: 0px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid green;">

    <div style="height: 50px; padding: 5px; border: 1px dashed blue;">
      top
    </div>

    <div style="flex-grow: 1; display: flex; padding: 5px; border: 1px dashed orange;">
      <div style="padding: 5px; border: 1px dashed blue;">
        left
      </div>
      <div style="flex-grow: 1; padding: 5px; border: 1px dashed blue; overflow-y: scroll;">
        center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>
        center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>
      </div>
      <div style="padding: 5px; border: 1px dashed blue;">
        right
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: min-height: 0 to the div where you have the orange dashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to limit the size of the child by using `max-height`. When you use `flex-grow: 1`, it allows the child element to grow to absorb extra space in the container, but it does not automatically limit its size to the parent's bounds when its content is too large.

Here's how you could fix it:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body style="height: 300px; max-height: 300px; margin: 0px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div style="height: 100%; max-height: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column; margin: 0px; padding: 5px; border: 1px solid green;">

    <div style="height: 50px; padding: 5px; border: 1px dashed blue;">
      top
    </div>

    <!-- Set max height as you'd like -->
    <div style="flex-grow: 1; display: flex; padding: 5px; border: 1px dashed orange; max-height: calc(100% - 50px);">
      <div style="padding: 5px; border: 1px dashed blue;">
        left
      </div>
      <div style="flex-grow: 1; padding: 5px; border: 1px dashed blue; overflow-y: scroll;">
        center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>
        center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>center<br/>
      </div>
      <div style="padding: 5px; border: 1px dashed blue;">
        right
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In that case `flex-grow: 1` does not do much - I could directly use calculated `height` instead of `max-height`. I simplified my case and set `50px` in the upper child. But what if its height is not fixed? Then I cannot use `max-height` in the lower child. What to do?

Comment: In this case CSS Flexbox would probably fix or answer your needs. Make the container a flex container with a column direction, and then allow the children to flexibly adapt their heights while ensuring the scrolling content does not exceed the parent's bounds.

`.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 300px; 
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}`